# mask coloring with mantaining the color intensity(gradient, shading) OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, semantic-segmentation

I am doing instance semantic segmentation and my main goal is to be able to change the color of the detected objects in the image. I obtained the mask and now when it comes to coloring I can't figure out how to maintain the intensity of the color from the original object so the colored one doesnt look so artificial.

Let me explain it on example. The image below represent the walls masks. Now I want to have the masks reflect original shading/intensity/gradient ( I am not sure what exactly plays a major part here), so the walls after coloring look normal.

images comparison:

[Image using cv2.min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isclh.png)

[raw mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owFQO.png)

I tried doing cv2.min and just multiplying the mask by the original image in the location of coloring just with /255. normalization, It is better but I still feel like there is some much cleverer way to do it.

```
color = (195, 123, 150)
rgb[markers == clicked_pixel] = color 
rgb = cv2.min(rgb, rgb_copy)
# alternatively 
rgb[markers == clicked_pixel] = color * (rgb_copy[markers == clicked_pixel]/255)

painted = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(rgb)
painted = pygame.transform.scale(painted, size)
display.blit(painted, (0, 0))
```

Comment: Show your code and your output result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you could use the cv2.seamlessClone function to seamlessly blend the colored mask with the original image.

Comment: Or use the original image as a texture map for the colored mask.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that is what I am doing right now. The problem is that the colored mask looks unnatural because the color is evenly distributed and doesnt mantain the original object's color gradient/shading.